# Return method of a sql query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, return

Good afternoon guys, I created a query for the return of sql but I can not change the return to return it
Next, I can return return the query inside the method but if I want to pick the method to add a combobox or to work with the returned value I can not only return it inside the method.

How can I change this method to use a return?

```
private void onClickLocalizarCidadePorEstado() throws Exception {
        CidEstController cc = new CidEstController();
        try {
            List<Cidade> c = cc.buscaCidadePorEstado(uf);
            for(Cidade cidade : c)
                System.out.println(cidade.getNom_cidade());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente!n" +
                            e.getLocalizedMessage()
                    );
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Contato n&atilde;o localizdo ou n&atilde;o existe!n" + 
                            e.getLocalizedMessage()
                    );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain more?...I am not clear what your asking.

Comment: There is no SQL query in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method's return type from `void` to `List<Cidade>`, then replace the `for` loop with `return c;`.  (You could also remove the `c` variable and just do `return cc.buscaCidadePorEstado(uf)`.)

You'll still need to return something even when an exception occurs.  You could put `return null;` within each of your `catch` blocks, or `return Collections.emptyList()` if you don't want the calling method to have to check for null results.  Alternatively, you could throw a different exception type instead — for example, `throw new CityLookupException(e);`.  (You'd need to create that class, of course.)